# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 921600 into shape (224,224,3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras, deep-learning

I trained a model using Transfer Learning(InceptionV3) and when I tried to predict the results it shows:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 921600 into shape (224,224,3)
```

The image generator I used to train the model is:

```
    root_dir = 'G:/Dataset'

img_generator_flow_train = img_generator.flow_from_directory(
    directory=root_dir,
    target_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,
    subset="training")

img_generator_flow_valid = img_generator.flow_from_directory(
    directory=root_dir,
    target_size=(224,224),
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,
    subset="validation")
base_model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(input_shape=(224,224,3),
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights = "imagenet"
                                               )
```

The implementation code is:

```
  cap=cv.VideoCapture(0)
  facedetect=cv.CascadeClassifier(cv.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
  model=load_model('Signmodel.h5')
  while cap.isOpened():
        sts,frame=cap.read()
        if sts:
            faces=facedetect.detectMultiScale(frame,1.3,5)
            for x,y,w,h in faces:
                    y_pred=model.predict(frame)
                    print(y_pred,"printing y_pred")
                    cv.putText(frame,y_pred,(x,y-30), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.75, (255,0,0),1, cv.LINE_AA)
```

I tried to resize the frame:

```
frame=cv.resize(frame,(224,224),3)
```

but when doing so I got:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(32, 224, 3)
```

What should I do to resolve this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: **complete** traceback please. and then you'll need `cv.resize` because your `frame` isn't of shape `(224,224,3)` and can't be reshaped into that, it has to be resized as an image

Comment: How should I resize the frame as image if cap.read() is returning numpy array? Github link: https://github.com/Nehasatya/sign-language-translator.git

Comment: 224*224*3=150528, not 921600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resizing and reshaping the image into required format solved the problem for me:

```
while cap.isOpened():
    sts,frame=cap.read()
    frame1=cv.resize(frame,(224,224))
    frame1 = frame1.reshape(1,224,224,3)
    if sts:
        faces=facedetect.detectMultiScale(frame,1.3,5)
        for x,y,w,h in faces:
            y_pred=model.predict(frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try converting your image to grey first?

detectMultiScal() requires an image in format CV_8U.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/de5/classcv_1_1CascadeClassifier.html#aaf8181cb63968136476ec4204ffca498

```
cap=cv.VideoCapture(0)
facedetect=cv.CascadeClassifier(cv.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
model=load_model('Signmodel.h5')
while cap.isOpened():
    sts,frame=cap.read()
    if sts:
        frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces=facedetect.detectMultiScale(frame,1.3,5)
        for x,y,w,h in faces:
                y_pred=model.predict(frame)
                print(y_pred,"printing y_pred")
                cv.putText(frame,y_pred,(x,y-30), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.75, (255,0,0),1, cv.LINE_AA)
```

Comment: ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "inception_v3" (type Functional).

    Input 0 of layer "conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (32, 224)

    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 224), dtype=float32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None                                                                                                                                   I got the above error while converting into grayscale,

Answer (score -1):

i see you have mentioned TL, i am going to assume you are using one of the VGG Models, i used one of them for drowsiness prediction, i got the same problem when i tried to use an image of 28x28 size, i got the error informing me that the size constraints won't allow me to adapt it to the input size 224x224, so i did something i used glob function to increase the size of the images from the size to enlarge them to 224x 224 size, the problem is if the image you are using has sensitive data(though i guess you are using it for real life data since you are using working camera instead of picture loading) the pixel distortion will destroy all and any kind of sensitive data.

Hope it helps...

Comment: you "used glob function to increase the size of the images"? please explain how that makes any sense.

Comment: I didnot use glob function to increase the size, i used functions to resize them, the only drawback was the images came out blurry which was no use to the dataset since i could not enlarge each image separately, i had used glob function(in this case so that i can take an image from a file resize it and store it in another place without disturbing the dataset) in python to apply it on the batch of images.